# porque me da error al momento de instanciar la clase Car

Tags: python, python-3.7

Tengo el siguiente ejemplo de codigo, pero al momento de ejecutarlo me da error

```
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, brand_name):
        self.brand_name = brand_name
    
    def getBrand_Name(self):
        return self.getBrand_Name
    
class Cost:
    def __init__(self, cost):
        self.cost = cost
    
    def getCost(self):
        return self.cost
    
class Car(Vehicle, Cost):
    def __init__(self, brand_name, model, cost):
        self.model = model
        Vehicle.__init__(self, brand_name)
        Cost.__init__(self, cost)

    def getDescription(self):
        return self.getBrand_Name() + self.model + "is the car and it's cost is: " + self.getCost()

if __name__ == "__main__":
     c1 = Car("Audi", "r8", "2cr")
     print("Car description: ", c.getDescription())
```

Este es el error que da:
c1 = Car("Audi", "r8", "2cr")
^^^
NameError: name 'Car' is not defined. Did you mean: 'chr'?

Comment: Estas definiendo el bloque `if __name__ == "__main__"` **dentro de la clase**, quita un nivel de sangrado a todo ese bloque condicional, debe estar a nivel global. Ademas, tienes mas errores tipográficos, `print("Car description: ", c.getDescription())` debe ser `print("Car description: ", c1.getDescription())` y en el metodo `getBrand_Name` en vez de          `return self.getBrand_Name` debe ser `return self.brand_name`. Por cierto, te recomiendo seguir las convenciones de estilo para código Python, los métodos deben usar snake_case: https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, brand_name):
        self.brand_name = brand_name
    
    def getBrand_Name(self):
        return self.brand_name  # Corregir el nombre del atributo

class Cost:
    def __init__(self, cost):
        self.cost = cost
    
    def getCost(self):
        return self.cost

class Car(Vehicle, Cost):
    def __init__(self, brand_name, model, cost):
        self.model = model
        Vehicle.__init__(self, brand_name)
        Cost.__init__(self, cost)

    def getDescription(self):
        return self.getBrand_Name() + " " + self.model + " is the car and its cost is: " + self.getCost()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c1 = Car("Audi", "r8", "2cr")
    print("Car description: ", c1.getDescription())
```

Correcciones y mejoras realizadas:

Corregir el nombre del atributo en getBrand_Name: En lugar de return self.getBrand_Name, debería ser return self.brand_name.

Corregir la llamada a getDescription: En lugar de c.getDescription(), debería ser c1.getDescription().

Añadir espacios en la descripción: En el método getDescription